# How to add Wordpress plugins to static (non-Wordpress) web sites?

Tags: wordpress, plugins

Suppose I want to add some Wordpress plugins (e.g. [Easy Appointment](https://wordpress.org/plugins/easy-appointments/)) to a few *static* web sites that do not run on Wordpress. Currently, I want to add just basic plugin features (appointment form and calendar) to my sites. In future, I would like also to add plugins for email notification, payments, etc.

My sites consist of a few HTML and JS files. I will probably need to use some cloud database or CMS but I don't want to move the sites to Wordpress. What is the best way to integrate Wordpress plugins with these static web sites ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You Can't Do That™.

Without WordPress there's nothing to run your WordPress plugin code: no php, no way to load it, no way to invoke its features. And there's no database to hold your data (both appointment forms and calendars are data-intensive applications.)

Could some sort of headless WordPress instance be used with its REST API? Probably not: most plugins generate the HTML, Javascript, and CSS to provide their functionality within WordPress pages. Few support the REST API, and those that do use it for limited purposes.

You can embed a calendar from another calendar web app (like Google's calendar) in your static site easily. If you can find an app that offers a way to embed forms you can use that too. Try searching for *appointment app to embed in static web site* and you'll find some candidates.